# Animar fondo de pantalla

Tags: javascript

tengo la siguiente duda.

Quiero animar el body de una pagina pero no logro hacer que me funcione tengo esto como codigo.

No se que podria estar haciendo mal.

```
    body{
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background: linear-gradient(130deg, #ff0000, #0000ff, red, green, blue);
    background-size: 100%;
    animation: animacion 10s ease-in infinite;

}


@keyframes animacion{
    0%{background-position: 0% 50%;} 
 
    50%{background-position: 100% 50%;}
 
    100%{background-position: 0% 50%;}
}
```

el html se ve asi

```
  <body>

    <p> Hola </p>

    
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

este es mi resultado

```css
html{
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background: linear-gradient(130deg, #ff0000, #0000ff, red, green, blue);
  background-size: 500% 100%;

    animation: animacion 7s ease-in infinite;
    
  background-size: 100% 100%;

   
    
}

@keyframes animacion{
    0%{ background-size: 100% 100%;} 
    50%{background-size: 120% 120%;}
    100%{background-size: 100% 100%;}
}
```

```html
<body>

</body>
```

buscando en internet encontre que con linear-gradient el fondo se auto genera y acomoda pero como quieres modificar el body o el html estos ya tienen el ancho y alto definido, por eso no se puede mover.
lo que hice fue usar el tamaño para generar una ilusion de movimiento.

y también le puse el efecto al html pues si se coloca al body este no se comporta bien.